# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined in IE 10

Tags: json, visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-10, iis-8

I'm using IE 10 Compatibility on Windows 8,
I'm getting this error while running the WebApp in Debug mode(VS 2012).
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined
Code below

```
var data = JSON.stringify(GetUserDetails());

function GetUserDetails() {
    var userData = {};
    userData.userName = $('#txtUserName').val();
    userData.password = $('#txtPassword').val();
    return userData;
}
```

Also , the strange fact is the same code hosted in IIS 8 runs fine in IE 10 Browser.
Any inputs?

Comment: This is not answer to your question but i just want to add that when you are dealing with IE browser you shouldn't depend it to Convert object to JSON or JSON to object. I suggest use some samll other JS libraries to do such functions like [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) .

Comment: I had the <!DOCTYPE html> tag in my markup but continued to receive the error until I de-selected Compatibility View in the IE 10 tools menu.

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the expected behavior because JSON will work only in the standard mode as per the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE8 and up [only have](http://caniuse.com/#feat=json) the `JSON` object in [*standards* mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx). So you need to make sure the document has a doctype.

Comment: Thanks , this looks to be the answer ... When I check IE 10 has it and IE 10 compatibility doesn't have it. IE 10 has like <!-- DOCTYPE html  -->  whereas IE 10 Compatibility has as <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""> ... not sure why it was commented ....

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad: IE10 definitely has `JSON`. Again, it's only available in standards mode.

Answer (score 3):

I found out for me that it was an **IE 10** compatibility's intranet setting that was raising this exception for my intranet sites:

**"Display the intranet sites in Compatibility View"**

To change this flag, or just to simply disable it, display the "*Command Bar*" in IE 10, then select "*Tools*" > "*Compatibility View Settings*" and un-check the option - second from the bottom. Fixed the issue immediately.

[image]

Comment: The DOCTYPE actually translates the same , you can say both are implicit

Answer (score 1):

You need to include json2.js

see [json2 inclusion](http://www.blakepell.com/Blog/?p=405#comment-2181)

for more details. There are cases where we have to deal with cases where clients use IE7 standards. So our code had to cater to such cases too. Ours being a retail website is accessed by hundreds of clients who use IE7 standards. Including json2 solves this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "JavaScript runtime error ...JSON is undefined" running Windows 8 and IE 10, while trying to run an ASP .NET application using Visual Studio 2010 development web server.   When I opened the browser, clicked "Alt" to display the menu, then clicked Tools->Compatibility View Settings and unchecked "Display all websites in compatibility view", I stopped getting the error.